# Python code Error "name 'screenCnt' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new in python and I created anaconda environment and running given code but it's showing error

```
   for c in cnts:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

        # our approximated contour should have four points
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = approx
            break

# show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
#print("STEP 2: Find contours of paper")
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

#     apply the four point transform to obtain a top-down
#     view of the original image
    warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
```

Error is

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>       122 # show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
>       123 #print("STEP 2: Find contours of paper")
>   --> 124     cv2.drawContours(orig, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
>       125 
>       126 #     apply the four point transform to obtain a top-down
>
> NameError: name 'screenCnt' is not defined

but in code I already defined screenCnt. initially, this code was running properly but now it's not working or it's show error after every alternate execution. (it run properly the first time and when restart kernel giving same error).

or if i set screenCnt = 0 or screenCnt = None it giving error

> error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>       123 # show the contour (outline) of the piece of paper
>       124 #print("STEP 2: Find contours of paper")
>   --> 125     cv2.drawContours(orig, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
>       126 
>       127 #     apply the four point transform to obtain a top-down
>
> error: OpenCV(4.2.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function
>   'cv::drawContours'

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, probably the statement `screenCnt = approx` is never hit during the execution. Try initializing `screenCnt` to some default value.

Comment: If I set screenCnt = 0 outside the loop its gives this error. OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'cv::drawContours'

Comment: In your case, I don't think "0" is a good default value. Try using the following if-else condition.

```
# Initialize screeCnt to None 
screenCnt = None
....code

if screen_cnt is None:
    # Do whatever is required when screenCnt is not defined here
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: given more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the screenCnt variables in lines 81 and 83 are not of the same. Or either you are trying to access the screenCnt which is defined locally within the scope of the if statement.

Comment: Not understand can you please explain in brief.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, neither `0` nor `none` meets the data type required by the second parameter of cv2.drawcontours, The specific details of the function can be seen here https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Analyze the data type. `cnts` is a set containing multiple contours. Each contour taken out during the cycle is defined as `cnt`. `cnt` is a point set defined by multiple two-tuples, so we can initialize it like this `screenCnt = [[0,0], [255,0], [255,255], [0,255]]` to initialize with a contour.

Answer (score -1):

It is showing not defined because the program could not detect 4 definite points in the image. Try to place the paper on a dark background.